# How could I find out what my desktop environment or window manager is from a command line command?

Tags: window-manager, desktop-environment

Is there a command line command to see which DE or WM you are currently using?

Comment: [How to determine which window manager is running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running); [How can I find which desktop enviroment I am using?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125062/how-can-i-find-which-desktop-enviroment-i-am-using)

Answer (score 3):

Just install `neofetch`, you will have detailed info of your system. In Debian based distros:

```
$ sudo apt install neofetch
$ neofetch
```

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               xxxx@pxxxx
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: MS-7C39 1.0 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.11.0-34-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 2 days, 14 hours, 32 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 3329 (dpkg), 6 (flatpak), 14 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1600x900, 1366x768 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Papirus [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       CPU: Intel i5-9400 (6) @ 4.100GHz 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               Memory: 6049MiB / 7828MiB
```

To get just the desktop environment name and version (if present), you can do:

```
$ neofetch | awk -F: '/DE/{print $2}'
 GNOME
```

Comment: @Quasímodo Indeed it has the `--off` option to hide the logo.

Answer (score 1):

at least in Debian based system you can simply run
`echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`
to determine your Desktop Envorinment.
For the Window Manager run
`wmctrl -m`
(sudo apt-get install wmctrl)